# Is there any way to prevent screenshot in React Native IOS version 0.63?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native, screenshot

Is it possible to disable screenshots in React Native app for a specific page in IOS?

I have already used the RN AppState feature to hide the content when the App is inactive or in the background state but this feature does not seem to work to prevent screenshots.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a user from taking screenshots check out the following npm:

https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot-poc

For iOS, we can't force to prevent users from taking screenshots but we can handle this as per the npm documentation.

Comment: I have already tried to add an overlay screen but it does not seem to work as expected. 
For IOS, This library only sends the notification after the screen capturing.

Comment: You aren't getting the blank screen while the screenshot was taken?

As in ios there no possible way to prevent users to take the screenshot. but we can use the hack to show a blank screen to prevent users to access app data.

Comment: No, I am not getting a blank screen while screenshotting. What would be the hack to show a blank screen? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: To integrate the ScreenShieldKit, we have to contact them on https://screenshieldkit.com/ to get the SDK.